# Resource level authorization with Signalr

Tags: signalr

Should Signalr groups be created with resource level IDs?  For example `dispatchedTrucks-123`, and `dispatchedTrucks-456`?  So that way when someone tries to connected to a group, I can check to see if they have access?

Let's say there are two companies: Company1 (Id 123) and Company2 (Id 456), each company has employees, and each company dispatches their trucks.

If I'm creating a Signalr hub, is it best practice to create a `dispatchedTrucks` group per companyId, then check to see if that people has access to that company before adding them to the group?

```
public async Task AddToGroup(string groupName)
{
    var companyId = Context.QueryString["companyId"];

    if (HasAccessToCompany(companyId)){
      await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, $`{groupName}-{companyId}`); 
    } else {
      // What's the Signalr equivalent of a 403?
    }
}
```

So later in the application I can broadcast to an entire group, so the only people who receive the message is those who have access to that companyId.

```
  var companyId = Context.QueryString["companyId"];
  await Clients.Group($`{groupName}-{companyId}`).addDispatchedTruck(name, message);
```

The RESTful equivalent of what I'm trying to accomplish is:

UserA works for Company1 (Id 123).
UserB works for Company2 (Id 456).

UserA is only authorized to make a GET request to `/company/123/dispatched-trucks`
UserB is only authorized to make a GET request to `/company/456/dispatched-trucks`

If UserA tries to call Company2's resources, a 403 is returned.
If UserB tries to call Company1's resources, a 403 is returned.